# Gallery Shortcode: using size="full" doesn't call the actual thumbnail image size

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I have my Media settings set up so that my thumbnail size is 60x60 pixels and the "Crop thumbnail" box is checked. I can see in the /uploads folder that there are in fact perfect square 60x60 thumbnails being generated for all the images are being uploaded.

However, when I use the gallery shortcode like this:

[gallery size="thumb"]

It's not actually calling that image thumbnail file. What it is outputting instead is the originally uploaded image source file and scaling it down using width="" and height="" attributes creating a proportional scale down to 60 pixels in width like this:

`<img width="60" height="45" src="/uploads/original-source.jpg" />`

But I need it to be doing this:

`<img width="60" height="60" src="uploads/original-source-60x60.jpg" />`

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: "thumb" is not a defined size. Use "thumbnail" instead. Or just [gallery] since the default size is "thumbnail".

Comment: I'm an idiot! "thumbnail" worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it thumb or full that is the problem?

Firstly, here is the codex page about the [gallery] shortcode

http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Notice that thumb is actually "thumbnail"

So its [gallery size="thumbnail"] for the thumb image.

If you are having issues with [gallery size="full"] then my initial thinking is that there are no images uploaded after you set the size in the post.

Try open the post again and upload fresh images and see if that works.

Comment: Agh, I'm so stupid: I didn't use "thumbnail"! That solved the issue of the actual thumbnail not showing up as a square.

Comment: these things happen ;)

What confused me is that in the question title you refer to full "using size=“full” doesn't call the actual thumbnail image size..." But you were after thumbnail actually..

Comment: I still have this problem (and have done the above). Any other ideas?